# Little conjecture about sums of reciprocals

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

Given a finite list $x_i$ of $N$ positive reals, it seems that $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i {}^{-1} \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \geq N$. Can anyone give me a proof?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz yields $\left(\sum x_i\right)\left(\sum x_i^{-1}\right) \geq \left(\sum \sqrt{x_ix_i^{-1}}\right)^2 = N^2$.

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: darij beat me to it!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz is an overkill. This is just the inequality between the arithmetic and harmonic means.


Comment: $a+1/a\ge 2$. Add and divide by 2. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Set $a_i=x_i^{1/2}$ and $b_i:=x_i^{-1/2}$. Then
$$N=(a,b)\le\|a\|\cdot\|b\|,$$
with equality if and only if $a$ and $b$ are colinear vectors. With your assumption, the right-hand side is precisely $\sum x_i$.